# How to assess relationship between responses to multiple likert items between two raters when there are multiple rater pairs?

Tags: correlation, likert, reliability, agreement-statistics

I have two data sets in which the same Likert scale questions were answered by two different responders. I want to calculate which level they are correlated.
My data set is like

```
WorkerID    Question    Worker_answer     Employer_answer_about_his_worker 
1               1              3                       2
1               2              4                       3
1               3              1                       5
1               4              2                       4
.               .              .                       .
1               15             3                       2
2               1              4                       2
2               2              5                       5
.               .              .                       .
2               15             2                       3
```

Comment: You have two data sets. Do you have one or two different groups in each dataset? Your question is not formulated well. Please try to expand your question. Your data set is not properly demonstrated here.

Comment: Do you want a different correlation for each worker?

Comment: Do you actually mean you have a single data set (albeit collected in two different processes), as you have illustrated, with a worker's rating and their employer's rating on 15 questions for each worker?  Or is there another dataset additional to that you have shown us?  Some other questions - you want to see if what are correlated?  And why do you want to know? (correlation may be of no interest to some likely underlying research questions here).  Also, are there multiple workers per employer, because if so you will need to take into account an employer effect..

Answer (score 1):

There are correlation measures that could apply (such as a Kendall tau for example), but you might want to look at inter-rater agreement:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability#The_philosophy_of_inter-rater_agreement

Along these lines, this might be of some interest --

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2307/3315487/pdf